# Portlet temporaily unavailable message for Alfresco portlet in Liferay

Tags: java, portlet, liferay, alfresco

I followed the steps on http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/integrating-alfresco-web-client-as-a-set-of-portlets-with-liferay to integrate alfresco as a portlet in Liferay 5.2.3.
I am able to add the Alfresco portlet to my Liferay page, but it shows the message "Portlet is temporarily unavailable"

Any way to fix this ?
Thank You.

Comment: What is the error in the log file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ewernli.In the logs folder of liferay,i have 5 files : admin.2010-01-07,catalina.2010-01-07,host-manager.2010-01-07,localhost.2010-01-07,manager.2010-01-07 . All files except, catalina.2010-01-07 are empty, and catalina.2010-01-07 contains http://shrib.com/liferaylog

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you get that kind of error, it means that while starting the portlet a exception was thrown.
It means that errors have occurred while startup.